# Is there a way for me to find out the date when a specific cell was last modified in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2002

As the title states, I have a spreadsheet with a column full of float values (groceries payments I've made over time) and I would like to see when I entered the value into each cell. Is this possible or am I out of luck? The version I am running seems to be Excel 2002 from Office 365.

Comment: I don't think that's stored per cell, no. I don't suppose you have a sequence of nightly backups of the spreadsheet you could look back through?

Comment: You could monitor the changes using an additional worksheet, but you would have to think about which values you would monitor and how you would back them up e.g. monitoring cells in column C, backup B,C,and the Date/Time in one cell or many cells in the same row of the source data or just by Date/Time in the next empty row etc. If this is something you're interested in then edit your question with the details of your idea how it should be done and add some code.